# Resize Google Map + API v3

Tags: firefox, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API v3.

In Chrome, the map fits fine into the div element I set with width 200px and height 200px.
In Firefox, it tries to take up the whole screen. I noticed the styling code that google maps uses there is this line:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
```

I've been trying to modify this via the API to set the width to 190 and hieght to 190.

Does anyone know how to do this?

The CSS styling I used for the div was:
    div.map {
     height: 190px;
     width: 190px;
    }

I added this into my API call already thinking it would resize based on the div styling:
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')

Happy Holidays!!

Comment: do you mean the size varies in browsers on first load of maps.

Comment: size doesn't necessarily vary; just seems that Chrome makes it fit into the div whereas Firefox does not.

Comment: can you post your code, so i can take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to hard code your width/height in an inline style. I ran into the same problem. The reason is it uses the width/height to create the other elements within the map.. try setting your code as follows:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 190px; height: 190px; z-index: 0;">
```